# Google Web Login to Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, google-signin

Google's `platform.js` script for handling web logins can end in a callback to initiate some function in our code:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?onload=appStart" async defer>
```

In spite of the many Angular tutorials and examples, I have yet to find a way to have this callback execute in an Angular controller. **How do I connect this callback to an Angular controller or other appropriate mechanism of Angular?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to inject `$window` into my controller and direct third party code there. This is the result:

```
var app = angular.module('ga',[]);
app.controller('gac', function($scope, $window) {

    $window.appStart = function() {
        console.log('appStart()');
        gapi.load('auth2', initSigninV2);
    };

    // additional functions omitted. refer to demo
}
```

Note when third parties call functions in Angular, it may be necessary to update the scope with `$scope.$digest()`.

Demo: http://jameswclark.github.io/Google-Web-Login/